# jquery jsonp in for statement got unexpected result

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, jsonp

I was using jquery to do some jsonp-callbak in order to convert the IPs in the HTML to their geometry infomation. Here's part of the HTML sample:

```
<span id="1" name="ip">211.139.114.235</span>
<span id="2" name="ip">211.139.114.235</span>
<span id="3" name="ip">211.139.114.235</span>
......
<span id="12" name="ip">223.66.235.21</span>
<span id="13" name="ip">223.66.235.21</span>
<span id="14" name="ip">223.66.235.21</span>
```

You see that many IPs are the same, so I first put them in a `{}`, and do jsonp callback only once for one IP. So here's my javascript code, However I got a very strange result:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        ipList = {};
        $(function(){
            $('span[name="ip"]').each(function(index,DOM){
                ip = $(DOM).html();
                if (ipList[ip]==undefined){
                    ipList[ip]={DOMList:[],data:{}};
                }
                ipList[ip].DOMList.push(DOM);
            });

            console.log('Log 1=======',ipList);

            for ( ip in ipList){
                console.log('Log 2=======',ip);

                $.get("http://ipinfo.io/"+ip+'/geo', function(response) {
                    console.log('Log 3=======',ip,response);

                    ipList[ip].data=response;
                    var domList = ipList[ip].DOMList;
                    for( i in domList ){
                        $(domList[i]).html(response.region+' '+response.city);
                    }
                }, "jsonp");
            }
        });
    </script>
```

the three `console.log` display the following result in the Chrome(version 24.0) console(I did some pretty-print work on the result):

```
Log 1======= Object{
    211.139.114.235: Object{
        DOMList: Array[11]
        data: Object{}
        }
    223.66.235.21: Object{
        DOMList: Array[3]
        data: Object{}
        }
    }

Log 2======= 211.139.114.235
Log 2======= 223.66.235.21

Log 3======= 223.66.235.21 Object {ip: "211.139.114.235", city: "Haimen", region: "Jiangsu", country: "CN", loc: "31.8962,121.1727"}
Log 3======= 223.66.235.21 Object {ip: "223.66.235.21", city: null, region: null, country: "CN", loc: "35.0000,105.0000"}
```

the Last result given by `Log 3` is quite strange because the `ip` variable are the same!---they are all `223.66.235.21` while the variable `ip` in `$.get("http://ipinfo.io/"+ip+'/geo'...` is different, (you can also confirm this by the result in `Log 2` and the `response` variable which is given together with `ip` in `Log 3` )

Should the `ip` variables' result in `Log 3` be the same like `Log 2`'s, isn't it?

The above problem cause the code in the callback function only convert the last ip (223.66.235.21) to the last `response`'s data.
I can't figure out where's the problem .

Any help is appreciate, thanks in advance~

====================solved====================

Thanks for mottie's answer.

Althought the jquery jsonp callback function can access variable `ip` by closure, because the jsonp is asynchronous, so these functions are called after the jsonp result comeback. However at this time the `for` loop has finished, and variable `ip` is set to the last one in the `ipList` (Javascript has **no** scope of the `for` statement, so the `ip` is in the `$(function(){...`'s scope. ) . That's why both of the callback function get `ip` as the last one(223.66.235.21). They are just referencing the same `ip` !

Comment: You should be getting the ip for log 3 from the response: `console.log('Log 3=======',response.ip,response);` because remember the json is returned asynchronously. You might also want to collect all the ip addresses, then reduce down the data to remove duplicates.

Comment: @Mottie .Thanks for your answer. I've try your sugguestion and it's all right! But how did it happen? Shouldn't the `ip` variable be packed with the callback function in something a clousure? @mottie

Comment: The `ip` is defined within the `for..in` scope, not at all within the `$.get()` callback function. So since the ajax is asynchronous, it is executing the callback *after* the `for..in` loop has completed and therefore the value of `ip` will almost always be the last `ip` in `ipList`.